# How to draw horizontal stacked area chart by ios-charts

Tags: xcode, ios-charts

I am using iOS Charts by Daniel Gindi.

I need to draw horizontal stacked area chart ([Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RhSI.png)). But I cannot find similar charts in examples of the library. I am trying to customise Horizontal Bar Chart like in [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uk7xF.png). But I cannot to avoid square corners.

How can I draw line instead of bars with squared corners?
Is it possible in this library or I should use another one?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
Use line chart instead ,and set `drawFilledEnabled` to true.

But the filled area is between line and x axis, so you may need to rotate the chart.